# How to add custom condition beforeLoad without cache in magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am create plugin to add custom condition to all beforeLoad product collection. However, I have an issue. Example:

The user_1 access to abc.com/product with cookie inventory=XYZ beforeLoad function will run with condition inventory=XYZ and return product collection, the magento cached this page with product collection follow inventory=XYZ.

The user_2, user_n access to abc.com/product they don't have inventory or inventory=GHQ different with inventory cookie of user_1. But the Magento load product collection from cache it didn't run to beforeLoad function in my plugin. Thus, The product list result will same as result of user_1.

I was created function to call clear collection cache in magento before reload page. It work but it make the page load very slow.

Please help me, How to make the magento alway call to function beforeLoad in my plugin without reload page? or other solution to call to reload product collection with custom condition.

My code as below:

```
public function beforeLoad(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $subject, $printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
    {
        $areaCode = $this->_state->getAreaCode();
        $inventory_source = $this->_request->getParam("inventory");
        /*if(isset($_COOKIE["inventory"])){
                $inventory_source = $_COOKIE["inventory"];
        }*/
        if($areaCode == 'frontend' && $inventory_source != ""){
            $joinCondition[] = "e.sku = isi.sku";
            $joinCondition[] = "isi.source_code = '".$inventory_source."'";
            $joinCondition = implode(' AND ', $joinCondition);
            if (!$subject->isLoaded()) {
                $subject->getSelect()
                    ->join(
                        [ 'isi' => $subject->getTable('inventory_source_item') ],
                        $joinCondition,
                        []
                    );
            }
        }
        return [$printQuery, $logQuery];
    }
```

Thank you so much,
BienHV

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned "different inventory cookie" it sounds like you'd like to present different page content based on a cookie value.

If my understanding is correct then you'll benefit from configuring page variations using vary string.

Magento 2 Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html#configure-page-variations